# XAMPP keeps showing Dashboard/Welcome Page instead of the Configuration Page

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've just downloaded and installed XAMPP 5.6.11 and started all the tools from the control panel. I've seen that one of it's new features is that it has a Welcome/Dashboard page.

Previously, going to 127.0.0.1 would take me to a language selection page and then to a orange-yellow page where I could configure XAMPP. Now, going to 127.0.0.1 or hitting Apache's "Admin" button in the XAMPP Control Panel takes me to the dashboard/welcome page no matter what.

One curious thing: attempting to go to http://localhost/xampp/ shows me an empty directory listing. I figured perhaps my install was botched so I reinstalled XAMPP. Still no luck. Even tried installing Apache 5.5.27. Same problem.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue here, comparing the htdocs/xampp folder in 5.6.11 with 5.6.8 I saw all the files there are missing in 5.6.11. Copied the entire htdocs/xampp folder from 5.6.8 to 5.6.11 and worked fine.

Comment: Yeah... I've already gone back to a previous version actually. Is this a bug or something? Should it be reported to Bitnami? That's what I'm wondering...

Answer (score 23):

Open the htdocs folder there will be index.php file.
In that file script is written to go in dashboard folder and show dashboard.
So you just have to comment it or delete that script and write any code save it and run http://localhost now dashboard screen will not open and you will see what you have written in that file.

Comment: That'd work. But what I'm looking for is a way to actually get to the XAMPP configuration page...

Comment: I commented it and it worked. I'm just wondering if you have an explanation as to what is happening?

Answer (score 10):

Delete the file(index.php) from your xampp folder, you will get the list of directories and files from htdocs folder.

Comment: it is not recommended to delete the default file as you may need them in the future or your application may not work correctly. another thing is you can redirect localhost to any directory or file from that index.php.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solutions that worked for me:

1. open `index.php` from the `htdocs` folder
2. inside replace the word `dashboard` with your database name.
3. restart the server

This should resolve the issue :-)

Answer (score 5):

Hey here is the solution for windows 7+.

**You need admin rights to make changes to the hosts file**

**Right click on your favorit text-editor and select "run as administrator" before opening the file**

Open the following file "c:/windows/system32/driver/etc/hosts"

Enter the line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Next: Define a virtual host in /xampfolder/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost  127.0.0.1>
  DocumentRoot "c:\your\document\root"
  ServerName localhost
    <Directory "c:\your\document\root">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      Options All 
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Restart your apache!**
Now you can enter http://localhost in your browser and access your page.

**Pro-Tip:**
You can use other names as localhost or have multiple localhosts this way. Just enter the names in the hosts file and define your virtual hosts.

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved the issue, by going to setting and permalink, just choose post-name.

it should work and you'll see the exact page.. rather than dashboard/xampp page again

Best of Luck

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution for this to remove the index.php code which is allocated on

```
xammp-> htdocs-> index.php
```

you can delete the code of this page to solution your problem but have another way which is .htaccss file.
Some time you show this problem because of have some issue or miss code on .htaccss file thas way yo saw the xammp dashboard every time.
Hop it will resolve your problem.
Happy Coding and Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion: Choose a different version. I had the same problem you have deinstalled v5.6.11, downloaded and installed v5.6.3, works fine for me.

cheers!

Comment: Mm hmm... I've already done that and merged a previous version's htdocs/xampp with the current version. Stuff works fine now. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Where could I download previous version of XAMPP?

Comment: I found it, its here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Answer (score 1):

(MAC)
check the /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf file
there is a section that by default is commented out. Search for "Virtual hosts". If you delete the # in the next line, like in the picture, you should just need to restart apache and then you're good to go. [uncomment to allow virtual hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdfZP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue. 5.5.24 was the latest version that worked for me. The Apache Friends blog has a post, https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20150723.html, that mentions the newer versions shipping with the 'Dashboard'.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/

The old version, but the desired function will be sufficient.

Uninstall version 5.6.11 and downgrade to version 5.6.8.

Comment: Please explain your answer, not just link to something

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows; didn't check Linux but don't see why it wouldn't work. Download the zip files for 5.6.8 portable.  Unzip the files and copy the xampp/htdocs to the xampp/htdocs in your install directory.

Comment: I think this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled the 6.8.14 and installed back older version 5.6.8, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the document root in the file C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf to the folder where is the index.php of your project.

Comment: in that case if you run any other project it  will keep showing the same project as the one set on document root

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
go to htdocs and rename index.php to anything, restart. Now everytime you access locahost it will show the directory not that annoying dashboard.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31624765)

Answer (score 0):

Put this as the first line in `c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`  (and restart the web server):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

So, it should look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This works for me. Right, it's already version 8.2.4and the url is http://localhost/dashboard/

Remember to restart Apache on XAMPP Control Panel.