# Xampp Settings for localhost

Tags: php, url, xampp, localhost

I cant see my xampp settings: using this URL `http://localhost/xampp/`

This is the **result** im looking for:

[image: This is what im trying to see]

I dont know why but if i look at examples, everyone's URL looks like `http://localhost/xampp/` if i use this Url i get a page saying:

> **Object not found!**  The requested URL was not found on this server.

The directory is located in **C:\xampp**, and if i just add `http://localhost/` as domain i get the tree structure of everything within **C:\xampp\htdocs**.

Also using Xampp v3.2.2 , if im in control panel and click on the Apache `Config` tab it open my file structure as mentioned above everything within **C:\xampp\htdocs**.

I just want to mention im using Windows, not Mac, but i meen both windows and mac has these Apache settings afcourse, i just dont get it how i cant find it using `http://localhost/xampp/`.

Apache & MySQL is switched on.

**What i think could be the problem:**

Could it be that im missing the `/xampp` directory within the `/htdocs` directory ?

> Im not sure if there should be a xampp directory in htdocs but its the
>   only thing that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

> Possible reason: Something is running with port 80

when you run Xampp, check the apache port no. ex: if it is displaying port 8012

then your url is `http://localhost:8012/dashboard/`
[image]

> Check Directories for Xampp

**Xampp** directories. 
[more about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653694/xampp-keeps-showing-dashboard-welcome-page-instead-of-the-configuration-page)

For check all dependencies in the : `httpd-xampp`

Comment: thanks for replying, this is not the case, my port is `Port : 80, 443` ?

Comment: well i can access that directory which opens the file structure for htdocs.. since you have yours running can you maybe check if you have a /xampp directory within your /htdocs? i think im missing that.. been along time since i used xampp so maybe when installed i deleted it like 2years ago...

Comment: `http://localhost/xampp/` is the URL and everything after localhost is usually located in htdocs, agree?

Comment: So if you look within your htdocs directory can you see a folder `/xampp` ?

Comment: search for `httpd-xampp` in apache folder, all configuration file must be in there.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i see is the xampp file should be located in the htdocs folder at least that is how i have it.
However i do not think that this will cause a problem for you in developing anything.

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: hi , thanks for that, i also feel thats the problem, i copied someone else xampp files that was in htdocs to mine, also the index.php all the files, and it did not work.. but then again it wasnt the same version as mine, so im thinking about reinstalling, also yes everything works , but my problem is i really want to know whats the issue , and  i know i can change the settings within php.ini but i cant see all the settings as i wish to like my image shows in question.