# codeigniter4 access web localhost from another computer

Tags: php, xampp

how do i access my localhost from another computer, example like
my ip : 192.168.2.10

and then another computer access using this url
http://192.168.2.10:8080

i tried to change httpd.conf xampp like

Listen 192.168.2.10:80

and this
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">

```
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

but still not working

thanks

Comment: Another computer within your home network, or outside your network?  Within your home should work, but from outside will likely take some changes to your router.
https://www.makeuseof.com/host-website-using-pc-or-laptop

Comment: hi, its inside my home network. recently i tried to tweak the httpd.conf but somehow it redirect to xampp homepage

Comment: i only can access xampp homepage and phpmyadmin mysql but i couldnt access index.php

Comment: OK, it sounds like you CAN access the host from another computer, but not the page you're expecting? I would reinstall XAMPP, there are a lot of StackOverflow questions like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP keeps showing Dashboard/Welcome Page instead of the Configuration Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653694/xampp-keeps-showing-dashboard-welcome-page-instead-of-the-configuration-page)

Comment: if you are able to access XAMPP, phpMyAdmin from another computer then you have access. The issue is how you are accessing your XAMPP web directory. If on the local system it is `http://localhost/webapp/index.php` then from the other system it will be `http://192.168.2.10/webapp/index.php` - it is best to modify hosts file on both systems to point to a domain like `http://webapp.loc` as from Codeigniter4, you have to access the public folder for index.php. `Start Here ->`[Codeigniter Docs for Virtual Hosting](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/running.html#virtual-hosting)